# Failed to loading lifelines (Result shows: Attribute error: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'logsumexp')

Tags: python, scipy, lifelines

I am trying to run the lifelines package,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd
from scipy.special import logsumexp
from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter, CoxPHFitter
from lifelines.statistics import logrank_test
```

And the results turn out

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2f2a9dd88e46> in <module>
      4 from scipy.special import logsumexp
----> 5 from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter, CoxPHFitter
      6 from lifelines.statistics import logrank_test

~/.virtualenvs/stats/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lifelines/__init__.py in <module>
     12 from lifelines.fitters.aalen_johansen_fitter import AalenJohansenFitter
---> 13 from lifelines.fitters.log_normal_fitter import LogNormalFitter
     14 from lifelines.fitters.log_logistic_fitter import LogLogisticFitter

~/.virtualenvs/stats/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lifelines/fitters/log_normal_fitter.py in <module>
      4 import autograd.numpy as np
----> 5 from autograd.scipy.stats import norm
      6 from lifelines.fitters import KnownModelParametericUnivariateFitter

~/.virtualenvs/stats/lib/python3.7/site-packages/autograd/scipy/__init__.py in <module>
      6 try:
----> 7     from . import misc
      8 except ImportError:
      9     pass

~/.virtualenvs/stats/lib/python3.7/site-packages/autograd/scipy/misc.py in <module>
      5 from autograd.numpy.numpy_vjps import repeat_to_match_shape
      6 
----> 7 logsumexp = primitive(scipy.misc.logsumexp)
      8 
      9 def make_grad_logsumexp(ans, x, axis=None, b=1.0, keepdims=False):

AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'logsumexp'
```

I understand that the logsumexp has been removed from scipy.misc and place in scipy.special. And previously some recommend to downgrading the SciPy to 1.1.0 version. However, will it be easier if I change the code from

```
logsumexp = primitive(scipy.misc.logsumexp)
```

to

```
logsumexp = primitive(scipy.special.logsumexp)
```

And if it is possible, may I know how can I modify the code? Is this code in Scipy.misc or is this code in lifelines?

Comment: Take a closer look at the traceback.  You'll see that the error arises from code in the package `autograd`.  It has been fixed in the master branch of `autograd` (https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/issues/501), but it looks like there hasn't been a release of `autograd` for quite a while.

Comment: lifelines has scipy pinned at 1.2.1 to avoid this error. https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines/issues/725